# Use URL Parameter to Preselect Option by Label not Value

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

How can I pass the label, not the option, to have javascript preselect from a dropdown?

For example, let's say the URL is `page.html?option=name3`

and in the form there's a select like this

```
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4">Name4</option>
</select>
```

In this example Name3 and 3 are different.

What javascript could be used to preselect the option whose text contents match that of the URL parameter above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selectedIndex of your element using javascript as follows. First, parse the url to get the desired query option. You can use `window.location` API to get the url and do your operations on it. Then, iterate through each option of your select element and determine a good match using some logic.

I hope this helps.

```html
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4">Name4</option>
</select>
<script>
   // to get option we use some parsing:
   function getOption(url) {
     var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);
     if (queryString){
       var optionString = queryString.split('=')[1];
       // returns string for options if specified.
       return optionString;
     }
     // return null otherwise.
     return null;
   }
   var e = document.getElementById("select-box");
   // var o = getOption(window.location.href);
   // var o = getOption(document.url) // does not work for Firefox
   // replace this with one of the lines above for dynamic solution
   var o = getOption('page.html?option=name3');
   if(o) {
     for(var i=0; i<e.options.length; i++) {
       if(o === e.options[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
        // be careful about case sensitivity and try to come up
        // with your own logic on how you validate this,
        document.getElementById("select-box").selectedIndex = i;
       }
     }
   }else {
    // if no option default to 0
    document.getElementById("select-box").selectedIndex = 0;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I won't be able to hard-code the index number, unfortunately, because the select is dynamically populated, and would change over time.

Comment: ah I see, I misunderstood your question and have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: using the revised answer, there was a console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: NULL is not defined`. I removed the line that says `return NULL;` and the error disappeared. However it still doesn't seem to work as intended.

Comment: You're right, I had misspelled e.options and null should be lower case. Now its fixed, and you can run the snippet to see the results. I'm passing the function getOption() a static string that you provided, make sure to replace that with the url in your solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Read the query param from the current page's URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
const optionParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('option'); // "Name3"
```

and than set the *Select* `value` to the option which `textContent` matches

```js
// const optionParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('option');
const optionParam = "Name3"; // (PS: Use the above one instead, this is for demo)

const sel = document.getElementById("select-box");
const opt = [...sel.options].find(op => op.textContent===optionParam);
if (opt) sel.value = opt.value;
```

```html
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4">Name4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried to build a minimal working example using this code, and mindful of your PS, but it did not work as expected.